# Задача. Упростить запись

Tags: c++

Суть задания: написать функцию `vector<int> findCar(double vol, vector<int> Perevozchik)`. где vol это объём который необходимо перевезти, Perevozchik это вектор содержащий имеющиеся в наличие секторов объёмы баков. И надо из имеющихся баков выбрать несколько баков в которых можно залить весь объём, при этом надо выбрать сумму объёмов баков как можно ближе к значению vol. На выходе должно быть суммарный объем секторов бака(первое значение) и номера секторов которые необходимо взять. К примеру (vol=7000, Perevozchik={7150, 0, 5970, 2015, 19951, 6000, 3070, 4990, 4130}). То в результате должно быть(7005, 4, 8) Так как 2015+4990=7005 это самое минимальная комбинация которая превышает 7000. Я решил это так и только для комбинация состоящих от 1 до 4-х секторов, но должно быть как-то проще:

```
vector<int> findCar(double vol, vector<vector<int>> Perevozchik) {
vector<int> sectionNum = {MAX,0};
for (int a1 = 0; a1 < Perevozchik.size(); ++a1) {
    int sum = Perevozchik[a1];
    if (sum >= vol && sum < sectionNum[0]) {
        sectionNum = { sum, a1+1 };
    }
}
for (int a1 = 0; a1 < Perevozchik.size()-1; ++a1) {
    for (int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < Perevozchik.size(); ++a2) {
        int sum = Perevozchik[a1]+Perevozchik[a2];
        if (sum >= vol && sum < sectionNum[0]) {
            sectionNum = { sum, a1+1 , a2+1};
        }
    }
}
for (int a1 = 0; a1 < Perevozchik.size() - 2; ++a1) {
    for (int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < Perevozchik.size() - 1; ++a2) {
        for (int a3 = a2 + 1; a3 < Perevozchik.size(); ++a3) {
            int sum = Perevozchik[a1] + Perevozchik[a2] + Perevozchik[a3];
            if (sum >= vol && sum < sectionNum[0]) {
                sectionNum = { sum, a1+1 , a2+1 , a3+1};
            }
        }
    }
}
for (int a1 = 0; a1 < Perevozchik.size() - 3; ++a1) {
    for (int a2 = a1 + 1; a2 < Perevozchik.size() - 2; ++a2) {
        for (int a3 = a2 + 1; a3 < Perevozchik.size() - 1; ++a3) {
            for (int a4 = a3 + 1; a4 < Perevozchik.size(); ++a4) {
                int sum = Perevozchik[a1] + Perevozchik[a2] + Perevozchik[a3] + Perevozchik[a4];
                if (sum >= vol && sum < sectionNum[0]) {
                    sectionNum = { sum, a1 + 1 , a2 + 1 , a3 + 1, a4+1};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

return sectionNum;
```

}

Comment: А чем не устраивает полный перебор всех вариантов? Почему только до 4? Это так надо или у вас просто не получилось иначе?

Comment: Задача выглядит как типичная задача на динамическое программирование, прямо руки чешутся... И тогда там не будет кучи вложенных циклов, а будет один линейный массив. Можно глянуть здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zQcD_4QLlI&t=1s&ab_channel=Rucode_Festival - там не видео главное, а комментаии к нему

Answer (score 2):

Господа,

руки чесались невыносимо, так что я попрбовал решить эту задачу в чуть чуть более общем виде, причём я на самом деле не знаю, называется ли то, что я применил, динамическим програмимрованием. Если Вас это заинтересовало - можете написать в комментариях.

Сначал объясню идею.

Мне нужно перебрать все возможные комбинации "перевозчиков", а потом выбрать из них те, которые обеспечивают перевозку необходимого объема, но при этом как можно меньше превышают его.

Пусть у меня есть некотрый набор таких кобинаций (не полный набор, а некотрое промежуточное состояние).

Что я могу сделать? Я могу посмотреть на каждую их этих комбинаций перевозчиков, и, если она УЖЕ обеспечивает перевозку нужного объема - то дальше делать ничего не надо. Нет смысла добавлять перевозчиков в тот набор, который УЖЕ перевозит столько, сколько надо.

А вот если комбинация перевозчиков не даёт перевезти нужные объем - я могу "дописать" к этой комбинации какого то еще не задействованного перевозчика. А также - добавить его объем. И получу новую комбинацию.

Получение таких комбинаций из исходной я в программе вынес в "порождающую функцию" func_generator().

далее, в [терминологии ДП](https://wiki.algocode.ru/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%94%D0%9F):
Индекс в массивае `dp` - это набор из ёмкостей.

Можно представить его как список, в который входят "выбранные для заполнения" ёмкости. И этот список - это ИНДЕКС в массиве. У меня этот индекс имеет тип set, где элементы, входящие в set - это объемы.

(При этом я пользуюсь тем, что все объемы различны. Для того случая, когда среди объемов могут встречаться одинаковые - нужно перейти от использования объема как индекса к промежуточному массиву, хранящему объемы, а в набор будет доаьвляться индекс из этого промежуточного массива)

Также, я ввел понятие "шага". На нулевом шаге мой "справочник" состоит из одного элемента [{}, 0] - что означает, что если перевозчиков нет вообще, то такая комбинация способна перевезти нулевой объем.

На первом шаге я добавляю в комбинации перевозчиков по одному перевозчику, а в перевозимые объемы - перевозимый им объем.

Ну, и так далее.

Формат ввода:

В первой строке файла `input.txt` записано число "перевозчиков"

во второй строке файла записано число `volume`

начиная с третьей строки файла записаны объемы перевозчиков.

Я (для упрощения решения) считаю, что все перевозчики - разные и положительные.

Пример входного файла:

```
    8
    7000
    7150
    5970
    2015
    19951
    6000
    3070
    4990
    4130
```

Сама программа, щедро снабженная комментариями:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <set>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;

    vector<int> volumes;

    // "порождающая функция". ей на вход подаётся набор первозчиков и volume, ими перевозимый
    // На выходе - она возвращает map из наборов перевозчиков, дополненных одним из незадействованных, и перевозимый ими volume
    map<set<int>, int> func_generator(const set<int>& src, const int& src_vol){
        map<set<int>, int> rez;
        for( const int& per : volumes )
            if (!src.contains(per)){
                set<int> new_key;
                for( const int& t : src)
                    new_key.insert(t); // делаем копию src
                new_key.insert(per);   // добавляем к этой копии нового перевозчика
                int new_val = src_vol+per;
                rez[new_key]=new_val;
            }
        return rez;
    }

    int main(){
        ifstream inp("input.txt");
        int N;
        inp >>N;
        int volume;
        inp >> volume;
        
        int t;
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
            inp>>t;
            volumes.push_back(t);
        }
        // Это - "массив" (на самом деле - map), отображающий "набор перевозчиков" -> "перевозимый ими объем"
        map<set<int>, int> dp;
        // инициализируем начало массива
        set<int> zero;
        dp[zero]=0;
        // начинаем расширять массив dp.
        // на каждом шаге (step-номер шага) этого расширения мы делаем вот что: берем все возможные комбинации перевозчиков, 
        // построенные на предыдушем шаге (то есть те ключи из dp, в котрых размер set'а равен step-1) 
        // Если по этому ключу в dp уже лежит перевозимый объем>=volume - ничего не делаем
        // Если для этого набора перевозчиков преевозимый объем <volume
        // то дополняем каждый такой ключ всеми возможными комбинациями перевозчиков, еще не задействованных в нём
        // в конце шага считаем, сколько добавлений мы сделали в dp. Как только ни одного добавления сделать не удаётся - 
        // всё, "заполнение массива" закончено, мы создали полный справочник "какие наборы перевозчиков могут перевести какой объем".
        int sizediff=0;
        int step=0;
        do{
            step++;
            cout << "step " << step << " calculating" << endl;
            int dp_size_beg = dp.size();
            for( const auto& [key, val] : dp ){
                if ( key.size()==step-1 && val<volume ){
                    map<set<int>, int> next_generation = func_generator(key, val);
                    for( const auto& [key, val] : next_generation )
                        dp[key] = val;
                }
            }
            int dp_size_end = dp.size();
            sizediff = dp_size_end-dp_size_beg;
        } while (sizediff>0);

        cout << "dp.size() = "<< dp.size() << endl;

        // Теперь нам из полного "справочника" всех возможных наборов перевозчиков и перевозимых ими объемов 
        // надо выбрать тот набор, который ближе всего "сверху" к требуемому volume
        set<int> xxs_set;
        int xxs_volume = *max_element(volumes.begin(), volumes.end());
        for( const auto& [key, val] : dp ){
            // и теперь надо сравнить все эелменты с этим, если при сравнеии удаётся уменьшить разницу между volume и текущим vol - сделать присваивание
            if ( val>7000 && val < xxs_volume ){
                xxs_set = key;    
                xxs_volume=val;
            }
        }

        cout << "min set: " << endl;
        for ( const auto& item : xxs_set )
            cout << item << endl;

        cout << "volume of min.set: " << xxs_volume << endl;  
    }
```

Вывод программы:

```
    step 1 calculating
    step 2 calculating
    step 3 calculating
    step 4 calculating
    dp.size() = 47
    min set:
    2015
    4990
    volume of min.set: 7005
```

Comment: Что означает "динамическое программирование" ? Это имеет отношение к типизации?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan - Нет, не имеет. Это, грубо говоря, метод сведения решения задачи к решению похожей задачи с меньшим значением входного параметра. В моём решении предложенной в вопросе задачи, скорее всего, можно говорить просто о оптимизированном переборе всех вариантов

Comment: А насколько это эффективнее полного перебора - вы не смотрели?

Comment: Насчет полного перебора: смысл в том, что мы "обрубаем ветви", по котрым нет смысла двигаться дальше. Представим себе, что перевозчиков не 8, а, к примеру, 80. Тогда полный перебор становится просто невозможен, но если объемы перевозчиков достаточно большие (то есть, не надо набирать 20-30 перевозчиков, чтобы перевезти весь объем) - приведенный алгоритм сработает за разумное время.